# how to remove -g option for g++ in Makefile generated by autoconf/automake

Tags: g++, autoconf, automake

I use automake/autoconf to generate Makefile for my project, and find that these Makefile call g++ with -g option.
I totally have no idea where have I set this, so how can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default settings of autoconf for `CFLAGS` is `-O2 -g`. If you want to override it you can do

```
./configure CFLAGS="-O2"
```

and this will avoid passing -g altogether.